# Contact forms on Magento redirects to same page

Tags: php, forms, magento

I'm having a problem with my contact forms on Magento, it doesn't validate and after clicking on the submit button it does nothing and redirects to the same page. It happens with the main contact form and also the footer form. I haven't changed anything and I'm using the "Indepent" theme. This is the link: http://platzchen.com/camisetas/contacts/index/

Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixes or solution:

Suggestion:
Always read carefully validation library documentation as well as basic implemented example.

Offical validation library used on your site is at link :
https://github.com/atetlaw/Really-Easy-Field-Validation

after testing and implementing below missing stuff code start working as required.

Missing code :

In footer: before body tag

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  new Validation('contactForm'); // OR new Validation(document.forms[0]);
</script>
```

In head tag:

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/prototype/1.6.0.3/prototype.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/scriptaculous/1.8.2/effects.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

By doing above two thing validation working perfectly on email.
Please read above mentioned validation library code and example and 
give a try again.

Thanks
Hope it helps